# cudaMallocManaged causes Access Violation

Tags: c++, cuda

**Update**

I have run the (modified) code below on another machine with a GTX 780 and it does not have any issues.  It still does not work on my "GTX 680 Ti Boost" even with the newest drivers.  I am going to surmise that it is a hardware issue.

**Original [Updated]**

I found that if I run a program repeatedly, in my case to gather experimental data, it sometimes crashes with an access violation on cudaMallocManaged.  If the code does not crash it gives me an error "Could not allocate memory".

**Setup**

OS: Windows 10

GPU: GTX 650 Ti Boost w/ compute capability 3.0.

API: CUDA 7.0/7.5

**Compilation Command (Windows)**

nvcc code.cu -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" -m 64 -g -G -o code.exe

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void CudaTest(std::string msg, cudaError_t err) {
    if(err != cudaSuccess) {
        std::string errMsg(cudaGetErrorString(err));
        std::cerr << msg << ": " << errMsg << std::endl;
        std::exit(1);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int* d_Data;
    CudaTest("Could not allocate memory for d_Data",cudaMallocManaged(&d_Data,sizeof(int)));
    CudaTest("Could not free memory",cudaFree(d_Data));
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

**"Script"**

Here is the program written in Go that I use to test the above code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strconv"
)

func toInt(str string) int {
    res,err := strconv.Atoi(str)
    if err != nil {
        panic( fmt.Sprintf("Expected an integer but found '%s'\n",str))
    }
    return res
}

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) != 3 {
        fmt.Printf("usage: %s <iterations> <program>",os.Args[0])
        return
    }

    iterations := toInt(os.Args[1])
    program := os.Args[2]

    for i := 0 ; i < iterations; i++ {
        cmd := exec.Command(program)
        cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
        cmd.Stderr = os.Stdout
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("iteration=%d, Error running executable '%s', error: '%s'\n",i,program,err.Error()))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: generally speaking, the idea behind CUDA managed memory is that it should obviate the need for explicit `cudaMemcpy` operations.  I haven't fully parsed what you have presented, but at first glance your direction seems a little odd.

Comment: That memset is just from the original implementation I had a while ago before I moved over to managed memory.  I just left it to keep it similar to what I have.  I will put a description of what the program does in the question to clarify.

Comment: Code appears to be working for me up to your expectations on 660Ti, cuda 7.5, and win10. Perhaps try updating the drivers?

Comment: I don't see a memset in your code, so I'm not sure what you are referring to.  In your description this: "copy data from host to device"  should be **unnecessary**.  CUDA managed memory does that for you.  You should not need an explicit `cudaMemcpy`.   Furthermore, in host code, your `d_Data` pointer points to **host** memory. So I'm reasonably sure your `cudaMemcpy` operation with a direction of `cudaMemcpyHostToDevice`, although it's not throwing an error, is nonsense. I don't think you're grasping the concept of managed memory.  I also ran your code as-is on linux 10 times with no issue.

Comment: Memset was typo.  I know cudaMemcpy is unnecessary but it was left over from a previous iteration of the code I have.  Currently I cannot make any changes or update my drivers but  I will do so later and give feedback.  I will also test on two other machines to see if the problem appears there.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I updated my post.  I have tested it on another machine with no issue.  I have updated the driver and it still occurs with the GTX650 Ti Boost; so I will assume that my card is failing until shown otherwise.  Thanks for feedback on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem appears to have been caused by faulty hardware or a broken CUDA installation. The OP and others have successfully run the code on other machines and platforms without error.

[This community wiki has been assembled from comments to get the question off the unanswered queue]